# How to delete a DNS record in WHM/cPanel "Edit DNS Zone" page?

Tags: dns, cpanel, whm

I can change and add DNS records using the WHM Edit DNS Zone page, but I want to delete a single record and it's not obvious how to do it. There's no mention of it in the [manual page](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Edit+DNS+Zone) for the software.

How can I delete a single DNS record in cPanel?

There is a different tool in WHM for deleting DNS Zones but I suspect that will delete every DNS record for the domain, so I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 3):

1. Empty all the text fields for the record
2. Change the Record Type back to "Select"
3. Click Save at the bottom of the page

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Just change Record Type to "Select", then click Save.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest versions of cpanel, you have direct option/button to delete any DNS record.

[image]